# Put method in Angular

Tags: angularjs, express, crud

I have a expressjs controller

```
exports.update = function(req, res, next) {
var id = req.params.id
User.findByIdAndUpdate(id, req.body, function(err, user) {
    if (err) {
        return next(err);
    } else {
        res.json(user);
    }
});
}
```

and a route

```
app.route('/api/users/:id').put(users.update);
```

which is working fine to update user with Postman. However, my frontend part

```
$scope.updateUser = function(id) {
    $http.put('/api/users/' + id, $scope.userData)
        .success(function(userData) {
            console.log(userData);
        })
        .error(function(data) {
            console.log('Error: ' + data);
        });
};
```

is not working on data-ng-click="updateUser(userData._id)" button within a form like

```
<input type="text" class="form-control input-xs" data-ng-model="userData.username">
<input type="text" class="form-control input-xs" data-ng-model="userData.email">
```

I get a PUT /api/users/551d468b53ac2cef3b000001 200 35.887 ms - 390 Response. Please note the form is in a modal box. with {{ index }}

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#actionModal{{$index}}" data-ng-click="Clear()"></button>

<div class="modal fade" id="actionModal{{$index}}" tabindex="-1" data-role="dialog">
```

Comment: is the function being called successfully?

Comment: make sure the id in $scope.updateUser is not empty, otherwise the route would not be found

Comment: what is the error you get?

Comment: I have no error :( - Just get PUT /api/users/551d4f41692894ec3e000001 in Morgan

Comment: have you checked that updateuser function actually calling or not?

Comment: @Artefact please do not edit your question to reflect the answers you get. Now that you changed your request to : $http.put('/api/users/' + id, $scope.userData) in your post, my answer did not make sense anymore. So I deleted it.

Comment: Yes the function is calling api.users/id - its seems no params are send!

Comment: @Manube: Sorry for that

Comment: Check the value of $scope.userData and you are getting that value in the server or not?

Comment: is userData empty or  not returned? could you replace it by a string, to check if the success is triggered: console.log("userData");

Comment: Seems $scope.userData is empty = undefined

Comment: Try initialising `$scope.userData={}` in the controller first.

Comment: if initialising $scope.userData={}, i get Object {} in console

Comment: I edit the Question to show how the id is passed in the modal throught {{index}}. I am not able to get the params I try to edit in the modal

Comment: I made a test by passing {username: "toto"} and it is working as it should. How can I get the scope params before the put method ????