# Getting data from scope before put method

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is a question following my issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29431984/put-method-in-angular?noredirect=1#comment47034518_29431984).

I have an HTML page

```
<body data-ng-controller="usersController">
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Username</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Registration Date</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr data-ng-repeat="userData in users" >
                    <td><input type="checkbox"/></td>
                    <td>{{ userData._id }}</td>
                    <td>{{ userData.username }}</td>
                    <td>{{ userData.email }}</td>
                    <td>{{ userData.registrationDate }}</td>
                    <td>

                        <!-- Button trigger for Action modal -->
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#actionModal{{$index}}" data-ng-click="Clear()">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span>
                        </button>

                        <!-- Action Modal -->
                        <div class="modal fade" id="actionModal{{$index}}" tabindex="-1" data-role="dialog">
                          <div class="modal-dialog">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <form role="form">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                            <h4 class="modal-title">Users details for <strong>{{ userData.username }}</strong></h4>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                            <fieldset>
                                                <legend>User Details</legend>
                                                    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
                                                        <dt>User ID</dt>
                                                        <dd>{{ userData._id }}</dd>
                                                        <dt>User Login</dt>
                                                        <dd><input type="text" class="form-control input-xs" data-ng-model="userData.username"></dd>
                                                        <dt>User Email</dt>
                                                        <dd><input type="text" class="form-control input-xs" data-ng-model="userData.email"></dd>
                                                        <dt>Password</dt>
                                                        <dd><input type="password" class="form-control input-xs" data-ng-model="userData.password"></dd>
                                                        <dt>User Registration</dt>
                                                        <dd>{{ userData.registrationDate }}</dd>
                                                        <dt>Notes</dt>
                                                        <dd><textarea class="form-control input-xs text-left" placeholder="Type some notes…" data-ng-model="userData.userNotes"></textarea></dd>
                                                    </dl>
                                            </fieldset>
                                            <fieldset>
                                                <legend>Site Setting</legend>
                                                    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
                                                        <dt>Affiliate ID</dt>
                                                        <dd><input type="text" class="form-control input-xs"></dd>
                                                    </dl>
                                            </fieldset>
                                        </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-ng-click="updateUser(userData._id)">Save changes</button>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>

                                                </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

In the following code $scope.userData is empty.

```
$scope.updateUser = function(id) {
    var userData = $scope.userData;
    $http.put('/api/users/' + id, userData)
        .success(function(userData) {
            console.log(userData);
        })
        .error(function(data) {
            console.log('Error: ' + data);
        });
};
```

Each Action button in the Action Column is opening user details (by passing {{index}} in a modal displaying data in input form. I would like to update user detail from this modal but I am not able to get data from the form: $scope.userData is empty

Any help would be appreciated as I am newbee :)

Comment: should only need one modal , use angular-ui modal and pass `userData` to modal scope

Comment: I have almost 4 modals on the page

Comment: still only need one and pass the data to the modal scope , something like `<button ng-click="openModal(userData)">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution.

$scope.users[id] return undefined. $scope.users return an array of object like

Object1 {_id: "551d468b53ac2cef3b000001", username: "will", password: "****", email: "will@gmail.com"…}, 
Object2 {_id:…

Then I just create a function to read objects content to get the good one by id

```
$scope.updateUser = function(id) {
    var userArray = $scope.users;
    function search(id, array) {
        for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i].id === id) {
                return array[i] 
            };
        };
    };
    var userNewData = search(id, userArray);
    $http.put('/api/users/' + id, userNewData)
        .success(function(userData) {
            console.log(userData._id);
            console.log(userNewData);
        })
        .error(function(data) {
            console.log('Error: ' + data);
        });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

userData will be not available in the controller as controller scope and ng-repeat scope is different. ngRepeat create child scope from controller scope.

So you will have to find out userData from $scope.users using id or any unique key or index.

```
$scope.updateUser = function(id) {
var userData = $scope.users[id];
$http.put('/api/users/' + id, userData)
    .success(function(userData) {
        console.log(userData);
    })
    .error(function(data) {
        console.log('Error: ' + data);
    });
};
```

Comment: Please change data-ng-click="updateUser(userData._id)" to data-ng-click="updateUser($index)"

Comment: are you getting userData now? If yes, why not you take id from userData and passing to $http.put() ?

Comment: data-ng-click="updateUser($index) give me error 500 with 0 ad user ID

Comment: could you please share you $scope.users format? Is it object array?

Comment: Sorry. I am not sure to understand. I am using node and express for the CRUD api. Scope.user is JSON formatted. If I test with userData = {email : "test@test.com"} it works. I am able to get any data from main window but not from the built in bootstrap modal which is displaying same data the the main window.

Comment: var userData = $scope.users[ID] return undefined and $scope.users return all objects.